# keras conv1d input data reshape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use 1-dimensional CNN for binary Classification in Keras. I have a machine which continuously performs an action and my goal is to classify if that action is normal or anomalous.

To monitor the behaviour of each action, there are 4 sensors that collect 100 measurements. Thus, for each action, I have 4x100 = 400 data points. In a separate file, I have the label correspondig to each action. My dataset looks like this:

```
measurement ID | action ID | sensor 1 | sensor 2 | sensor 3 | sensor 4 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
       1       |     1     |   42.3   |   42.3   |   42.3   |   42.3   | 
       2       |     1     |   42.3   |   42.3   |   42.3   |   42.3   | 
       3       |     1     |   42.3   |   42.3   |   42.3   |   42.3   | 
      ...      |   ....    |   ....   |   ....   |   ....   |   ....   | 
      100      |     1     |   42.3   |   42.3   |   42.3   |   42.3   | 
       1       |     2     |   42.3   |   42.3   |   42.3   |   42.3   | 
       2       |     2     |   42.3   |   42.3   |   42.3   |   42.3   | 
       3       |     2     |   42.3   |   42.3   |   42.3   |   42.3   | 
      ...      |   ....    |   ....   |   ....   |   ....   |   ....   | 
      100      |     2     |   42.3   |   42.3   |   42.3   |   42.3   |
      ...      |   ....    |   ....   |   ....   |   ....   |   ....   |
```

My problem is how can I reshape this dataset to apply a convd1 in Keras. Also how to assign a label to a bunch of vectors. Note that my dataset is composed of 10,000 actions. My assumption is that I have 4 channels (dimensions) and a vector of 100 values for each one, so my input shape should be (maxlen=100, dimension=4). Maybe I am totally wrong.

The model should look like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5 activation='relu',input_shape=(100,4)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, momentum=0.9, decay=0, nesterov=False)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)
model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY), epochs=100, batch_size=100)
```

Can anyone point me which is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using number of sensors seems logical, and should not be a problem and considering multiple measurements as size also seems right. So, you can try training this model and check the results.

Another way that I'll recommend is to use different convolutions for all the sensors. So you'll have 4 convolutions each accepting input of shape `(100, 1)` from one sensor. The Keras code will look something like

```
from keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, Dense, concatenate, Flatten
from keras.models import Model

s1_input = Input((100, 1))
s2_input = Input((100, 1))
s3_input = Input((100, 1))
s4_input = Input((100, 1))

conv1 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(s1_input)
conv2 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(s2_input)
conv3 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(s3_input)
conv4 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, activation='relu')(s4_input)

f1 = Flatten()(conv1)
f2 = Flatten()(conv2)
f3 = Flatten()(conv3)
f4 = Flatten()(conv4)

dense_in = concatenate([f1, f2, f3, f4])
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense_in)

model = Model(inputs=[s1_input, s2_input, s3_input, s4_input], outputs=[output])
```

There is another RNN way as well, where you consider your 100 measurements as timesteps and input the data of 4 sensors at each step. But, I highly doubt this method can be superior to the CNN method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but could you further explain how can I use 1 convolution per sensor? I understand the input should be `(100, 1)` but how could I model it? Replicating this model 4 times or how. Sorry, I am a little bit confused...

Comment: You'll need to use [Functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) of Keras in that case. I have updated my answer to show how you can model the same.

Comment: Thank you for the code, now I can understand it better!

Comment: @layog is it accurate to picture the kernel here as being shape (5x1) and it moves down the 100x1 time series?